# How to add native iOS/Android screens to flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm very new to flutter and I got Idea how to add flutter screen into native app but my requirements is opposite.

In my app, I have a flutter app with Login flow and once login is done, I want to show native iOS/Android screens flow.

Could you please help me how to do this?

Any idea would be great.